# AngularFire include $firebaseArray or $firebaseObject error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Does anyone know why such a simple code returns me an error? When i include $firebaseObject i jave this same error :/

**angular.js:11383 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/unpr?p0=NaNirebaseArrayProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseArray%20%3C-%20SinglePageService**

**Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','firebase']);


myApp.factory("SinglePageService", ["$firebaseArray", function($firebaseArray) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://burning-heat-bbbb.firebaseio.com/users/');
    var items = $firebaseArray(ref);

    return {
        all: items,
        get: function (id) {
            console.log("service ID", id);
            var user = items.$getRecord(id);
            console.log(user);
            return user;
        }
    }
}]);



myApp.controller('SinglePage', function SinglePage($scope, SinglePageService, $location, $route) {

    var userId = $route.current.params.id;
    $scope.user = SinglePageService.get(userId);

    console.log("$scope.user", $scope.user);
});



    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok, link https://plnkr.co/edit/dEWHUlN5W4PBDqP81OXl?p=preview but problem is only when i includ $firebaseArray or $firebaseObject

Comment: OK i resolve problem.
i'm using 0.9.0 v angularFire and when i use 1.2.0 it works